# Android studio lag when try to edit XML file or drag and drop components

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Everytime i try to edit my XML file or i try to drag and drop components it keeps on lagging its too hard to edit my xml file but in java its works fine and no lag at all. I am using Lenovo Laptop with Intel Core i5 6200u with 12 gb of ram and android studio is installed inside the ssd. Please help

I tried making my laptop at high performance mode and adding memory allocation on for android studio max heap but still it doesnt work. I Also try to plug my laptop while using android studio in hope of having greater power source make it run smoother. I also tried to remove everything that is running in the background and run only android studio but still no help. In emulator i try to run android studio in physical device and not the emulator still no help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try if clean building the project helps. The layout editor can get very slow sometimes. In complex code where there are many injections etc., sometimes it doesn't work at all. So try to write layouts using XML editing instead of drag-and-drop.

Anyways, there is a new experimental setting in Android Studio:
File > Settings > Experimental > Layout Editor > Quality Setting.

Play with the slider and see if it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response. but I fix the issue by updating my android studio to flamingo.